# Using JS "match" to extract yearly salaraies from a job post string, but it's returning characters outside of the parens

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a TamperMonkey script to clean up LinkedIn results so jobs won't show if they don't meet certain criteria such as pay range. To do this I have the following:

```js
var payYr = $(jobItem).text().toLowerCase().trim().match(/\$(.+?k?)\/yr/g);
console.log(payYr);
```

I've tested the regex repeatedly on live test sites which confirm that the resulting set should be an array of ONLY the numbers between the $ and the '/yr' values. That will usually be $##/yr or $###/yr values.

Input would be strings such as:

$115K/yr - $145K/yr · 6 benefits
$180K/yr - $210K/yr

Expected output:

```
Array [ "115k", "145k" ];
Array [ "180k", "210k" ];
```

Instead, in Firefox, when I test it I'm getting arrays like so:

```
Array [ "$115k/yr", "$145k/yr" ];
Array [ "$180k/yr", "$210k/yr" ]
```

I can't figure out why the dollar sign and /yr values are being returned. By all accounts, that shouldn't happen and I don't know what's going on or how to fix it.

Comment: Please post a [mre] with an example of the text you're trying to extract from.

Comment: You have several `console.log()` calls in your code snippet. Which of them is that example output from?

Comment: I've uploaded the whole script. The output is from the console.log(payYr); in the Yearly pay section.

Comment: The "whole script" is not a MINIMAL example. We just need to see the text and the regexp extraction.

Comment: Get rid of the `g` flag. That's returning an array of matches of the entire regexp, not the capture groups.

Comment: Updated to the minimum code, input, expected output, and actual output. Removing the /g flag produces unwanted output in terms of matching only the first result and no others.

Comment: Without the `g` flag it will return the first match, with each array element corresponding to a capture group.

Comment: I need the last match in the string. That requires either regex that can retrieve only the last match or that returns all matches so I can pop it off the array to achieve the same result.

Comment: See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value) on `String.prototype.match()`. Namely: "_Return value:_ If the `g` flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups are not included. If the `g` flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned."

Comment: Thanks for the "capture group" terminology - that will help. Also thanks for clarifying that javascript can't do what I'm wanting. It's suprising, but so be it. I'll adjust the code to remove the superfluous characters.